# Probability of two people dealing the same card at the same time?

Tags: probability

I came across the following question while looking for math "tricks".

> Imagine that two people each hold a shuffled deck of 52 cards. One
>   person counts aloud from 1 to 52. On each count, both deal a card face
>   up on the table. What is the probability that at some point during the
>   deal two identical cards will be dealt simultaneously?

According to [this post (MAA website)](http://www.maa.org/community/maa-columns/past-columns-card-colm/in-his-own-words-mathematical-card-tricks-from-martin-gardner-1914-2010), the probability of the same card being dealt by both persons is approximately 17/27 or almost 2/3. Can you explain how that probability is derived?

I found [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204407/what-is-the-probability-when-using-two-separate-card-decks-that-the-same-card-wi) that appears similar but the accepted answer doesn't seem to come close to what I got through empirical testing :-)

Comment: Interesting problem. Would love to give it a go, but not good at combinatorial type probability. Someone will answer i ams sure...

Comment: I do this in class when I teach probability. Great fun, and the chance of identical cards is surprisingly high.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for are called: [derangements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

One can show that the ratio between derangements and permutations goes to $1/e$, so the probability to have a permutation of 52 cards which is not a derangement is, approximately,
$$ 
  1 - 1/e = \sim 0.63
$$

Comment: You mean 52 right, lol I tried calculating 1-!52/52! but I think wolfram alpha ripped me off and gave me 1-1/e

Comment: yes, corrected!

Answer (score 0):

The probability is $1-\frac{!52}{52!}$. Suppose that a certain person does it first but we film him. Now number each card as he deals it 1 to 52. Then if the other person doesn't coincide he must have obtained a derrangement of that permutation.